# The number of connections to this computer is limited - Remote Desktop Windows Server 2012 DS R2

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I am facing a weird problem with my Windows Server 2012 R2.

> The number of connections to this computer is limited and all connections are in use right now. Try connecting later or contact your system administrator.

I have not purchased any CAL licenses. I am using builtin free two RDP. However, at the moment all users are disconnected and their account is disabled as well. I have also deactivated and activated the license from RD Licensing Manager, but it also did not work for me. Although I am seeing the following users that their issued license/certificate will expire. And I can not revoke the CALs.
[image]

Restrict RD Services user to a single Remote Desktop Session is also disabled, Max connections are unlimited in the GPO as well.

I have also unpluged the cable and restarted the Server. This problem also happened few months back, then I noticed after the expiry date of the issued license, the RDP worked. I have Googled a lot but still, I am unable to resolve the issue. I am not sure, but is there any way to revoke the CAL? or remove/edit the Expire date to earlier?

I shall be grateful if someone could assist in this matter.

Comment: If you open task manager, and go to the Users tab, and you see the users still there, right-click them and select log off. As long as the Users tab doesn't show 2 RDP users, you should be able to log in.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But there is no user logged in. Task Manager>user tab only shows the current logged in user which I am.

Comment: It should work then. You can try rebooting. Also, you can run `quser` in cmd to see which users are currently connected according to terminal server.

Comment: Rebooted the server many times, unplugged and plugged the LAN, flushed the DNS. quser shows only one active administrator user. My assumption is that it will work when the user issued date expires, as you can see in the above image.

Comment: But you don't have the terminal services role installed right? Only stock RDP options? Otherwise you require CAL for it to work.